# Finding data from specific value in an array in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Morning All,

I have an Allowed systems field in my record that can contain an array such as: 22, 18, 21

What I want to do is if system 18 is accessing the database and is pulling all the records that are allowed for system 18, how can I write that in sql.

```
+----------+----------------+------------+
| AdvertID | AllowedSystems | AdvertName |
+----------+----------------+------------+
| 47       | 22, 18, 21, 3  | GeorgesAd  |
+----------+----------------+------------+
| 49       | 2, 7, 9, 6     | StevesAd   |
+----------+----------------+------------+
| 47       | 18, 12, 32, 8  | PetesAd    |
+----------+----------------+------------+
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Have a great day..!

Paul Jacobs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: I add a space to the beginning of the searched column and a comma to the end to account for the cases where 18 is the first or last entry in the list. I then search for ' 18,' within the string.

```
select *
    from YourTable
    where charindex(' 18,', ' ' + AllowedSystems + ',') <> 0
```

Answer (score 2):

This will test for the best performing cases first, in the hopes of getting some performance out of what is destined to be an inefficient query due to the denormalized structure.

The first two `WHERE` clauses can take advantage of an index on `AllowedSystems`, although this may be helpful in only a small number of cases, depending on what your data is like.

```
select AdvertID, AdvertName 
from MyTable
where AllowedSystems = '18'
    or AllowedSystems like '18,%'
    or AllowedSystems like '%, 18'
    or AllowedSystems like '%, 18,%'
```

Answer (score 1):

First, this is a bad idea for a data structure.  You should probably normalize by adding an `AllowedSystems` table with a record for each pair of system and Advert.

Second, you would want to use this:

```
SELECT AdvertID, AdvertName
FROM MyTable
WHERE AllowedSystems LIKE '%18%'
```

You're going to have issues when you get over 100 systems, since there is no way to tell if the hit is for `18` or `118` or `181`.

EDIT:

Or you can use RedFilter's multiple `WHERE` conditions to avoid the above issue with `18`, `118`, or `181`.

Answer (score 1):

The poor performance way would be:

```
SELECT AdvertID, AdvertName
FROM YourTable
WHERE ', ' + AllowSystems + ', ' LIKE '%, 18, %'
```

However, ideally you should have an extra table that has a compound key:

```
Table: AdvertAllowedSystem
AdvertID
SystemID
```

so that you can do a more performant, SARGable query:

```
SELECT a.AdvertID, a.AdvertName
FROM AdvertAllowedSystem s
    INNER JOIN Advert a ON s.AdvertId = a.AdvertId
WHERE s.SystemId = 18
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition if you have possibility to changed the design of create a materialized view, for this you may use [hierarchyid Data Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677173.aspx) or Rank and Unrank